# add LinkedResource from Properties.Resources in c#

Tags: c#, email, email-attachments, alternateview

Adding a jpeg picture to a mail message using

```
LinkedResource resPic = new LinkedResource(@"path\Pic.jpg", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
```

works well, but I need to add the picture from the project Properties.Resources.Pic.

How can that be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to save it to disk first:

```
var fileName = Guid.NewGuid.ToString();
var path = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)),
    fileName);
File.WriteAllBytes(path, Properties.Resources.Pic);

LinkedResource resPic = new LinkedResource(path, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
```

and then when you're done with the whole process, clean up the file:

```
File.Delete(path);
```

I'm not guaranteeing that you'll be able to cleanup the file in the same method, so `path` may need to be a more accessible variable, but you can work out those details.

Comment: @RuiM, I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Comment: The file cannot be deleted though, gives file being used by another process error. Not a problem for me, I'll delete it on the next invocation of the program (it's a schedulled task)

Comment: @RuiM, you need to make sure you totally dispose of all the classes that you used to popup the email message. They are using it.

Comment: @RuiM, that's a great idea!!